# Prevent Percent Character Transform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am attempting to use the Web Deployment Toolkit with our MVC3 project and overall the deployment works fine but our connection string to the database has a password that contains a percent (%) character that is followed by two numbers.  The deployment toolkit seems to be transforming this as a Hex character replacement.  Is there a way to prevent this character replacement and still keep the connection string usable on developer machines?  I tried putting in the replacement in the Web.Debug.Config file and even adding a %25 instead of just the % to try to have it replace just the % character and it still replaces the complete value.

Example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="server=Server1;uid=user1;pwd=abc123%72;database=Database1;"
</connectionStrings>
```

gets replaced with

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="server=Server1;uid=user1;pwd=abc123r;database=Database1;"
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Try using %% to escape the percent sign?

Comment: @Jacob - That gets it closer.  I put in "pwd=abc123%%72" and am getting "pwd=abc123%r" out after the transform.

Comment: How about this: pwd=abc123%%372

Comment: @Jacob - Still no go, now it outputs pwd=abc123r

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/212687/iis-7-0-web-deploy-authentication-fails-after-changing-windows-password-help seems to have the same problem, but no answer

Comment: Hi Adam, can you explain the steps you are taking and where it is failing? I cannot piece it together based on your question so its difficult to give a recommendation here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the pwd portion of the connection string to:

> pwd=abc123%252572

After much trial and error, I discovered that It does a double pass. The first pass will convert **%2525** to **%25**, the second pass converts **%25** to **%**. That is why when you used %2572, it resulted in r (%72 is the Unicode code for r). This seems to me like a bug in the parser. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can give a better explanation.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me.  I don't know if it is a bug or just undocumented operation of the parser but if someone has a better explanation I would be interested in it as well.  Thanks for finally coming up with a solution to the issue.  I had since "resolved" the issue by using the Parameters.xml file and making the connection string as a parameter, but I would have preferred to use the built in web/app.config functionality of specifying based on build type (Debug/Release/Production/Test, etc).

Comment: You are welcome. I wonder if this can be posted somewhere on MS site to get more attention. Glad I was able to answer, even if it was too late.

Comment: @mateuscb : This is reported yet a few years ago. [see here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a845f14d-be28-4ac4-b320-8ee5b9897150/bug-on-connection-string-when-publishing-password-with-percent-sign-) and the bug is still there. Replacing % with %25 just once helped for me.

Comment: @Peter If you were able to get it to work by only using `%25` then the issue seems to have been fixed. Back when I had this problem, we had to use `%2525`.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the exact same issue (with a different password of course).

To keep the connection string to the database working on the developer machines i've modified the publish settings to use a 'different' connections string.

For your example: 
web.config would contain:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="server=Server1;uid=user1;pwd=abc123%72;database=Database1;"
</connectionStrings>
```

Under the publish settings right-click project, select publish..., go to settings->databases. For the database MyDB, enter

```
 server=Server1;uid=user1;pwd=abc123%72;database=Database1;
```

This allowed my developer machine to retain it's connection to the database and the host machine to automatically use the correct connection string both by publishing directly or through teamcity.